# How to use seqeval classification_report after having performed NER with HuggingFace transformers?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition

I have followed [this tutorial](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#tok-ner) on a custom dataset of mine, and I have now a trained model.

I would like to use `seqeval`'s `classification_report` function so that I have a nice display of the performances of my model.

On which data should I call `classification_report`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `classification_report` on your training data first to check if the model trained correctly, after that call it on the test data to check how your model is dealing with data that it didn't see before.